# Address of register variable requested

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I am trying to simplify the following fragment of code:

```
void foo() {
    register int r0, r1, r2, r3;
    r0 = 0;
    r1 = 0;
    r2 = 0;
    r3 = 0;
}
```

by introducing constant-size array and a loop over it

```
void foo() {
    register int r[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        r[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

What I noticed is that it is not supported by some versions of compilers. Why?

- Clang 13 `error: address of register variable requested` https://godbolt.org/z/v7TKW8f68
- Clang 12 everything is ok https://godbolt.org/z/63vKE1nY4
- GCC 13 `error: address of register variable 'r' requested` https://godbolt.org/z/r6d86Wo7r

Comment: Because registers don't have addresses.

Comment: @ScottHunter so what? I am not trying to access register addresses here, right?

Comment: Array indexing implicitly involves addresses.  `r[i]` is the same as `*(r+i)`.

Comment: An array of 4 integers won't fit into a register

Comment: @dbush My intention is to have `r[0]` as a register. I would expect `r` to be a compile-time entity that holds a list of registers, so `*(r+i)` is not dereferencing any register and should be allowed.

Comment: @Gerhardh If I replace 4 by 1 it still doesn't work so this probably is not a reason of my issue.

Comment: does it really make sense to have an array which points to four different registers, allocated in memory, effectivelly pointing to stuff that doesn't have memory addresses? I see the point and idea behind this (shorter code, quickhand access to 4 registers paired under the same umbrella/variable) but I don't think it makes sense from a compiler's point of view. You'll just have to roll out a class/macro for this.

Comment: Did you notice that https://godbolt.org/z/63vKE1nY4 generates the exact same code with and without `register`? Anyway using `register` nowadays is pretty pointless is most cases. Maybe it makes sense with certain microcontrollers.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It's equally senseless in microcontroller programming, except for the cases where you have some godawful old compiler from the 1990s that couldn't optimize code well. Similar can be said about `inline`.

Comment: Why do you think using the `register` keyword is necessary or useful? In most cases the compiler (with optimization enabled, of course) is better in optimizing the code than you can do manually. An optimizing compiler will leave out the variables and assignments or even the whole function as the code does not not have any side effects. Try adding option `-O` in https://godbolt.org/z/63vKE1nY4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If the array object has register storage class, the
behavior is undefined.](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3).

Answer (score 2):

Here's what a draft for the ISO C23 standard has to say:

#### §6.7.1 Storage-class specifiers

> A declaration of an identifier for an object with storage-class specifier **register** suggests that
> access to the object be as fast as possible. The extent to which such suggestions are effective is
> implementation-defined.

> The implementation can treat any **register** declaration simply as an **auto** declaration. However, whether or not
> addressable storage is used, the address of any part of an object declared with storage-class specifier **register** cannot be
> computed, either explicitly (by use of the unary & operator as discussed in 6.5.3.2) or implicitly (by converting an array name
> to a pointer as discussed in 6.3.2.1). Thus, the only operator that can be applied to an array declared with storage-class
> specifier **register** is **sizeof** and the typeof operators.

For completeness:

#### §6.3.2 Other operands

##### 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators

> Except when it is the operand of the **sizeof** operator, or typeof operators, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of type" is converted
> to an expression with type "pointer to type" that points to the initial element of the array object and
> is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: C23 is not yet released and got lots of problems remaining still in the current draft, so it is best not to quote it until it is actually finished.

Comment: Fair point. The language used appears unchanged, AFAICT, from C11 -> C17 -> this draft, save for the former two making mention of `_Alignof` being valid alongside `sizeof`.

Answer (score 2):

> What I noticed is that it is not supported by some versions of compilers. Why?

Because C does not define the behavior when a (sub-)expression of array type decays to a pointer to a `register`-qualified type.  This happens when the element type is `register`-qualified, and it is consistent with the language constraint against applying the address-of operator to an object of `register`-qualified type.

The `register` storage class does not actually tell the compiler to allocate an object (only) in a register.  Rather, it requests making access to the object as fast as possible.  But in general, compilers will do this anyway when optimization is enabled, and they tend to be better than humans at determining how best to use the available registers.  The only reason to use `register` storage class in new code is if you want to ensure that an object cannot be the operand of the `&` operator.

As far as simplifying your code, this is already pretty simple:

> ```
> void foo() {
>     register int r0, r1, r2, r3;
>     r0 = 0;
>     r1 = 0;
>     r2 = 0;
>     r3 = 0;
> }
> ```

Adding a loop does not make it simpler, and definitely does not make it *faster* (which I assume is a consideration, because of `register`).

I would simplify it by removing `register`.  I might also use initializers instead of assignment statements:

```
void foo() {
    int r0 = 0, r1 = 0, r2 = 0, r3 = 0;
}
```

Or if you wanted an array for other reasons, then I would *definitely* remove the register and use an initializer.  This is about as clear and simple as can be if you want that array:

```
void foo() {
    int r[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
}
```